# Python Pandas Dataframe: user-defined function in groupby to merge columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to use in `groupby` a user-defined function that will be passed as arguments values of several columns, every column in a separate argument? In the following 'standard' example `sum` function is called on`v1` and `v2` columns separately:

```
In [110]: dct = {
     ...:     'id':[1,2,2,3,3,3],
     ...:     'vl':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
     ...:     'v2':[2,2,2,2,2,2]
     ...: }
     ...:
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
     ...: df.groupby('id')['vl','v2'].sum()
     ...:
Out[110]:
vl  v2
id
1    1   2
2    2   4
3    3   6
```

How to define `mysum` function with two arguments, with each argument to get it's own column something like:

```
def f(col1, col2):                                                                                          
    return  col1 * 2 + col2 * 3
```

So, in fact, this function merges two columns in one. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can unpack a `pd.Series` with `*` or `**` depending on what you need.  Or you can be very explicit with your lambda.

```
def f(v1, v2):                                                                                          
    return  v1 * 2 + v2 * 3

df[['v1', 'v2']].apply(lambda x: f(*x), 1)
# or
df[['v1', 'v2']].apply(lambda x: f(**x), 1)
# or
df.apply(lambda x: f(x.v1, x.v2), 1)

0    8
1    8
2    8
3    8
4    8
5    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What does `1` mean in ` f(*x), 1` ?

Comment: I ran `apply` on the `df` directly as opposed to after a `groupby`.  When doing it directly, I need to specify the axis in which I'm applying.  In this case, the axis was `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the group to a numpy array by accessing the `.values` property, then do the sum, as for `numpy.sum`, *The default axis=None, will sum all of the elements of the input array.*:

```
df.groupby('id')['vl','v2'].apply(lambda g: g.values.sum())

#id
#1    3
#2    6
#3    9
#dtype: int64
```

---

To get weighted sum:

```
df.groupby('id')['vl','v2'].apply(lambda g: (g.v1 * 2 + g.v2 * 3).sum())

#id
#1     8
#2    16
#3    24
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Running this I get `TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
`

Comment: Which version of python and pandas are you running, I got no error on pandas 0.19.x with both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
----
IPython 5.1.0

Comment: You may also check the key of the dictionary. It doesn't seem like the keys match the column names you are using in the `groupby` line.

Comment: Also I don't actually need to sum all elements, it may be any manipulation of arguments, for example `col1 * 2 + col2 * 3`

Comment: In that case, you can do `df.groupby('id')['vl','v2'].apply(lambda g: (g.v1 * 2 + g.v2 * 3).sum())`